# Can be Windows 10 home screen login password easily cracked if laptop is stolen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security

I have some important information in my laptop that I don't want to be accessible for case if my laptop is stolen. How good protection is Windows home screen login password? Can be easily cracked with some tools? Is there any other way to protect my data?

Comment: newbie - you probably should edit your question to add (a) who you expect to steal your laptop and (b) why you are leaving it unsecured. The average thief cannot simply walk into your computer. If they were that knowledgeable, they would be gainfully employed and likely have a computer better than yours and in no need of stealing yours.

Comment: @John: Laptops are portable and are *by design* often found outside the boundary of one's own home. No deep technical knowledge is needed to yoink someone's bag at a bus stop (possibly even before determining that it contains a laptop), nor does someone need to be specifically targeted by skilled hackers for that to happen...

Comment: Best protection: encrypt it with pre-boot authentication in place and never leave the machine running with windows booted when you are in an untrusted environment. Even when encrypted, if someone steals it and it's booted, he has some attack alleys. He does not have those if the machine is turned off, since he will need to overcome the encryption, first.

Comment: In addition: As a matter of fact, there was a design flaw in windows that, for 15 years, allowed bypassing the logon screen on domain joined machines! As you can imagine, Microsoft played it down, big time. Read https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-15/materials/eu-15-Haken-Bypassing-Local-Windows-Authentication-To-Defeat-Full-Disk-Encryption-wp.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Unless the drive itself is encrypted, or the data, in some container such as a [VeraCrypt folder](https://www.howtogeek.com/108501/the-how-to-geek-guide-to-getting-started-with-truecrypt/), is encrypted, the login password protection is *meaningless* if someone has **physical access** to your PC.

The password protects the PC from a casual passerby from logging in, but once someone has the machine, it is trivial to remove the SSD or HDD and read its data. Just as easy would be to boot from USB using almost any OS, e.g., [a live Kali Linux USB device](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/live-usb-install-with-windows/), and to copy all data, or even image the disk to attack at leisure..

Comment: If one uses the BIOS Drive lock (in tandem with Power On access) then someone with physical access needs this password. Moving the drive to another machine still requires this password. I have tested this.

Answer (score 1):

**Crack Password:**

> Can [the password] be easily cracked with some tools?

No, not if strong enough.

You likely have a Microsoft Account. This will have the same password as your laptop.

A 12 character password with numbers, letters and special characters will take about 3 thousand years to brute force crack with today's computers. Special characters eliminate third party cracking tools.

[Password cracking](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-an-8-character-password-could-be-cracked-in-less-than-an-hour/)

**Disk encryption:**

You can encrypt your main drive. That is another approach. You need to flawlessly remember the encryption Key. Numerous people in here have not and have lost their data.

If you are very well organized, by all means consider encryption.

**BIOS / DISK password:**

You did not specifically ask, but also use the Drive Lock in your Laptop BIOS.  Again, be organized and know what it is.

My own Lenovo drive has Opal security and that is transparent to me, but IF a person could get it out, they would not be able to access it.

Your own laptop likely has a BIOS power on / Drive lock password (quite common) **so be sure use this**. The BIOS drive lock prevents read access without the password stored in the BIOS, even if moved to another machine.

**Fingerprint / Face recognition:**

You can also use PIN and Fingerprint / Face recognition. That is secure. But keep a password in case of issues.

Overall, you can secure your computer so that any average person stealing it will not get your data.

Comment: I thought that it must be almost impossible, but then I found this article https://www.hackingarticles.in/multi-ways-to-crack-windows-10-password/ where it explains how you can replace password, not sure what to think now about it.

Comment: @newbie1234 - It's not applicaible to accounts linked to a Microsoft Account

Comment: Hm I am not sure if I ever linked account to Microsoft Account when I installed Windows.

Comment: With regard to using a Bootable (non-recovery) USB (a) keep Secure Boot ON and (b) if the person somehow boots, they cannot readily crack the password constructed to thwart it.  Windows Home likely got you to use a Microsoft Account - Windows 11 Home enforces this.

Comment: @John - Easily bypassed and only enfoced upon install time (but again bypassed

Comment: I added the need for Power On password. Not many people can easily break this. And then if no power on password, lots of people in here lose their passwords and cannot get in.